# Is MobFox really as good as they claim?

Tags: mobile, ads

Currently I have a few android apps running with AdMob. I heard that it is not good so I decided to switch from AdMob.

I searched online and found this MobFox claim that they pay 300% more than AdMob, which is pretty cool if it's true. You know they say if it's too good to be true, it's not. As I spend more time researching on it, it becomes suspicious. All the people saying good things about MobFox on the internet, are very likely MobFox employees.

So ...have anyone used MobFox before? Thanks,

Comment: I am also considering it, but I don't like this incredible happiness all over Internet with this network. In fact eHauler registered in StackOverflow the same day you arised the question...

Comment: @ompemi Yes that's exactly what I mean! Everyone saying good thing about MobFox is newly registered. Anyway, I think I will stick to AdMob a little longer since it announced it would incorporate AdSense. I would like to see how that goes then decide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am unhappy with mobfox. I began with Mobfox 10 days ago and the first day was great, i got near 1$, but next 10 days I have got 0$!, I had thousands of impressions and I have asked why i dont get any revenue and still they havent answers about this issue. Only revenue I am getting is from the backfill of Admob.

Answer (score 4):

My experience with MobFox has been been pretty good in that it beats admob on the European market. Fillrate in my experience is between 20% and 30% which is fine as long as you have admob as a fallback.

I wrote [a long blog post comparing my experiences with iAds, Admob and Mobfox](http://www.smallte.ch/blog-read_it_10003.html) which includes a table with actual numbers.

As you can see in this post MobFox now represents between 20% and 30% of my total ad revenue (and I make a comfortable living of it).

Comment: Unfortunately since I posted this data MobFox went seriously downhill. After the summer of 2011 it never went back to the original high revenue. At this point admob just makes more money now.

Comment: Does the situation is the same today? I live in Switzerland and I mainly focuses on European too.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that it really depends on where your traffic is coming from. I have currently added two (iPhone) apps on MobFox, one that has mostly european users, and one that is primarily successful on the Asian Market. I do have their eCPMcontol feature activated for both of these apps.

The first app give me a pretty good fillrate and an eCPM of $3.5, which is, at a 1,2% CTR, a lot higher than AdMobs
For the second app, the fill-rate is pretty poor as they don't seem to have any high CPC ads for Asian users, but I will soon try disabling the ecpm control for this app to see how the "real" fillrate and revenue would look like.

Both apps use admob as a fallback option. I am not using their built-in backfilling feature because it was not yet available when I integrated, so I am manually falling back with my own custom code.

I think it's definitely worth giving them a try if you have traffic from europe or the united states. After all, you can always use your old network to fill when you use the cpm control.

Answer (score 3):

No MobFox is not as good as they claim. I've been using them for a while now as backfill for AdMob. The first few days they were in fact (almost) as good as they claimed, with CTR and eCPM about twice AdMob's. Then suddenly they dropped, a lot. For the last few months, my MobFox CTR has been only about .01%, and eCPM is 1 cent or less.

Comment: My experience with MobFox on Android: terrible eCPM ($0.06, worse than AdMob which is already pretty bad), terrible CTR, awful dashboard with no geographic stats, buggy SDK... Don't waste your time.